# AWS CodeBuild errors out in provisioning step

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have a AWS CodeBuild project which is failing because of an error

> Internal Service Error: CodeBuild is experiencing issues

. This is happening on the "PROVISIONING" phase.
I have tried with different permissions on the AWS codebuild role but it did not fix this.

Can someone please help me out on this ?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Its look like your build is using environment variables that are two large for the codebuild to handle. This error is raised when the length of the environment variables exceeds the combined maximum of around 5,500 characters.

Try to reduce the environment variables or you can use Amazon system parameter to store large environmental variables and retrieve them from your buildspec file. To store large environment variables see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: I second the question. This is not the first time AWS error messages are rubbish (I've seen worse) but that is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this exact error when provisioning a windows container image to build a .NET core application. I found that `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8` works.

AWS has only a couple samples of using codebuild for windows products and they said the samples must use the above image, but it was ambiguous about whether *all* windows builds require that image. The image I initially tried was `mcr.microsoft/dotnet/sdk:5.0` It's a shame because the 5.0 sdk image is much smaller. Currently the framework image takes 9 min to provision for us.

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error message as ZeroGraviti due to the problem reported by bzuillsmith. The image I initially tried was mcr.microsoft/dotnet/sdk:5.0. After seeing this post I realized that mcr.microsoft/dotnet/sdk:5.0 is a multi-architecture image and that the default image may not be a windows image. Apparently, Codebuild does not set the architecture flag to match the environment type that you specify. I chose the latest windows image, and it was able to provision. Provisioning took ~7mins

mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.302-windowsservercore-ltsc2019